# how to get allowed maximum items count for a splist ?

Tags: splist

I'm querying list properties using a REST query **/_api/Web/Lists?&$select=Title,ItemCount**.

ItemCount property returns current count of items but I don't see **how to get the maximum allowed count for a SPList**   : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist_members.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the property is **not available by querying /_api/Web/Lists but only by querying _api/Web/Lists/SchemaXml** then parsing the xml

```
var url  = __site  + "/_api/Web/Lists(@v0)/SchemaXml?&@v0=guid%27"+listId+"%27";
$.ajax({
    headers:{
        Accept:"application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    url:url,
    success:function(res){
        var xmlStr = res.d.SchemaXml;
        var doc = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
        var xPathRes = document.evaluate ('//@MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation', doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
        if (xPathRes.singleNodeValue) {
            success(xPathRes.singleNodeValue.textContent);
        }                   
    },
    error:error
});
```

**or simpler by querying
/_api/Site/MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation**
(thanks ghangas for this one (as found on [REST API : different properties list using /_api/Web/Lists/SchemaXml VS /_api/Web/Lists/?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237924/rest-api-different-properties-list-using-api-web-lists-schemaxml-vs-api-we)))

So it looks like this limit is a property of the site and not per list.
Of course this property is not listed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite_members.aspx

Why KISS when you can go the MS way?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is based on you listview treshold setting. Default is it 5000 records.

Comment: You're telling me that the limit is not on the list itself but that there are 1 limit per (list)view ? This sounds strange to me. When does this value comes from when you're editing a list (=listedit.aspx) ? The threshold of which listview is used ?

Comment: This is just a general limit of how much item there can be return in one call/view. It is a general sharepoint setting, can be changed thru central administration. Is due to avoid heavy loads.